# Getting a stack trace from SBT with Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, stack-trace, sbt

Context: Writing Scala unit-tests in a project managed by SBT.

When I execute `sbt test` to run my unit-tests an assert fails somewhere in my code, I get something like the following (and nothing more):

```
Test com.reach.ml.test.TestLSHEasy.T0 failed: assertion failed
```

This tells me which unit-test caused the assert fail, but not which assert it was. If I run the same test directly (not using sbt), I get a whole stack trace, which is very useful for debugging. So my question: How do I get SBT to print out the stack trace when a test crashes?

Comment: Isn't `last test` showing you all the output of test execution?

Comment: No, the entirety of the test-related output when things work is:
"""
[info] Passed: : Total 9, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 9, Skipped 0
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Aug 22, 2011 11:33:29 PM
"""
If there's an error, there's just the line I first posted and another that says essentially the same thing.

Comment: What Geo meant is that, when `test` fails with exception on SBT, doesn't typing `last test` then shows the full exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding [xsbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt), it might be related to the [`util.log.StackTrace`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/d73762e20352991602f986cbe85204d0e9dfd4d8/util/log/StackTrace.scala) object which can trim its output.
The [issue 118](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/118) illustrated the will of keeping stack traces should be under better control:

> so you shouldn't see that trace by default.

Maybe you can wrap your unit test, intercepting any exception, and printing explicitely their *full* stack trace? (as in [`Basic.scala`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/88787d8569ac039e6455ac66d1ab99717d310e39/sbt/src/sbt-test/compiler-project/run-test/src/test/scala/Basic.scala) or [`Boot.scala`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/200581abc01e3ee9893c47e86b3a6106077f0e91/launch/Boot.scala)).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the developers went a bit overboard when trying to clean up error printing. In any case, SBT is a great tool and wrapping with try/catch blocks, while not ideal, isn't hard.